# how to backup file in java?

Tags: java, copy, backup, filechooser

In reality its just making a copy of a text.txt file. I know how to use file chooser to choose the file but that is as far as my knowledge really goes.

I can do this:

```
public BasicFile()
{
   JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser(".");
   int status = choose.showOpenDialog(null);

   try
   {
        if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) throw new IOException();

        f = choose.getSelectedFile();

        if (!f.exists()) throw new FileNotFoundException();
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
        display(1, e.toString(), "File not found ....");
   }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
        display(1, e.toString(),  "Approve option was not selected");
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to copy files?

Comment: Yes, I would love to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path object is perfect for copying files,
Try this code to copy a file,

```
Path source = Paths.get("c:\\blabla.txt");
    Path target = Paths.get("c:\\blabla2.txt");
    try {
        Files.copy(source, target);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I’m really sorry because my first example didn’t work at all, I just have copy it from a tutorial without trying it, but this code I tested and it works,

Answer (score 2):

If you have to backup a whole folder, you can use this code

```
public class BackUpFolder {

    public void copy(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation) throws IOException {
        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            copyDirectory(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        } else {
            copyFile(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        }
    }

    private void copyDirectory(File source, File target) throws IOException {
        if (!target.exists()) {
            target.mkdir();
        }

        for (String f : source.list()) {
            copy(new File(source, f), new File(target, f));
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException {
        try (
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BackUpFolder backUpFolder = new BackUpFolder();
            String location = "./src/edu/abc/locationFiles/daofile"; //File path you are getting from file chooser
            String target = "./src"; //target place you want to patse
            File locFile = new File(location);
            File tarFile = new File(target);
            backUpFolder.copyDirectory(locFile, tarFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BackUpFolder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), which explains the basics of `Input/OutputStreams` and `Reader`s and `Writer`s, which are used to read/write bytes of data from a source to a destination.

If you're using Java 7 or over, you should also take a look at [Copying a File or Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) which is part of newer `Files` and `Paths` API, which you can find more information about at [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

Comment: Oh no, I told some one to read the documentation and explore actual offical tutorials  shame on me for answering a broad and open end question with a broad and open ended answer

Comment: OMG, a MadProgrammer comment that [triggered the Queen heat detector](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49751373#49751373). Welcome to an esteemed club, since mine trigger this detector all the time (but I've never seen one of yours do this until now)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I've become sarcastic in my old age

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've always been that way, just had to turn the filters off :D